# Using template from themes in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have recently received an already built project and needs an update. Specifically in woocommerce. I am still a noob in wp and woocommerce so please do bear with me. In my wooccommerce, I would like to load my a php file that contains an html form in my woocommerce file. In themes, the previous programmer wrote it as:

```
<?php get_template_part('template-parts/my-page/user-info'); ?>
```

How I tried to use the same code in woocommerce:

```
<?php get_template_part('../../template-parts/my-page/user-info', null, (array) $user_info); ?>
```

But nothing happens.

The file structure is like this:

```
wp-content/themes/theme-name/woocommerce/cart/cart.php
wp-content/themes/theme-name/template-parts/my-page/user-info.php
```

I have a validation that before they proceed to checkout, they need to fill in some sort of data first.

Hope that you can enlighten me.